# How to Implement onBackPressed for Android Fragments(Tabs Activity)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I am developing an Android Application which contains the `Tabs` Activity. My `Tabs` activity contains four `tabs(Fragments--[1][2][3][4])`. What I want is when I press the Back button it must be redirected to the previous tab, not to the first tab. Like

```
[4] -> [3]
[3] -> [2]
[2] -> [1]
[1] -> Alert to logout from the App
```

Please help me out. What do I have to write in my `TabsActivity` class.

Comment: you can do it in 2 ways. first one is mentioned in answer. second one is to use
`instanceof` method like following way
 if (mFragment instanceof mFragmentClass) { // perform your logic
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use logics instead of hardcoding page numbers. 
Below solution works with 2,3,... n, every number of items in `Viewpager`.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() != 0) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
    } else super.onBackPressed();
}
```

If you are using **`TabHost`** then you can use [this solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25207785/6891563)

Answer (score 1):

**Assumption**

Your four fragments is hoted with ViewPager.

**Logic**

You can write your code into

```
 @Override
    void onBackPressed()
    {
    if(viewPager.getCurrentItem==3)
    {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(2)
    }
    else if{

    }
   }
```

and like wise

Answer (score 0):

In your attached Activity `onBackPressed()` you have to implement like below,

```
@Override
void onBackPressed()
{
   if(viewPager.getCurrentItem==3){
      viewPager.setCurrentItem(2)
   }
   else if{
     //do your stuff here
    }
}
```